# Resample audio using libsamplerate in windows phone

Tags: c++, resampling, wasapi, audio-capture

I'm trying to re-sample captured 2channel/48khz/32bit audio to 1channel/8khz/32bit using libsamplerate in a windows phone project using WASAPI.

I need to get 160 frames from 960 original frames by re-sampling.After capturing audio using `GetBuffer`  method I send the captured BYTE array of 7680 byte to the below method:

```
void BackEndAudio::ChangeSampleRate(BYTE* buf)
{

int er2;
st=src_new(2,1,&er2);
//SRC_DATA sd defined before
sd=new SRC_DATA;


BYTE *onechbuf = new BYTE[3840];
int outputIndex = 0;

//convert Stereo to Mono
for (int n = 0; n < 7680; n+=8)
{
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+1];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+2];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+3];
}

float *res1=new float[960];
res1=(float *)onechbuf;

float *res2=new float[160];

//change samplerate
sd->data_in=res1;
sd->data_out=res2;
sd->input_frames=960;
sd->output_frames=160;
sd->src_ratio=(double)1/6;
sd->end_of_input=1;
int er=src_process(st,sd);

transportController->WriteAudio((BYTE *)res2,640);

delete[] onechbuf;
src_delete(st);
delete sd;

}
```

src_process method returns no error and `sd->input_frames_used` set to 960 and `sd->output_frames_gen` set to 159 but the rendering output is only noise.
I use the code in a real-time VoIP app.
What could be the source of problem ?

Comment: Did you convert from integer to float samples first? Meaning, does `buf` contain integer samples, or float samples?

Comment: You have a memory leak here: `float *res1=new float[960];` because you reassign to `res1` immediately after, loosing the only pointer to the allocated memory.

Comment: @Nabla Thanks for your hint.I'm not well at c++.But I don't think it is the main issue.

Comment: @harsini No it is not, thats why I posted it as comment, but you will run into trouble sooner or later when your program takes all your systems memory.

Comment: How dd u generate bsamplerate dll ? cn we get the winmd file directly ?

Comment: It's for almost 2 years ago and I don't remember how I generate that.:-/

Comment: Thank you :) . Finally I managed to add the lib in to my project. And it generate 160 frames. But the rendering output is only noise :( . I am doing exactly what you posted in the answer  . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure that your captured buf is not silent?I mean your capturing works fine?

Comment: finally found the issue. I was providing 16 bit input data. but libsamplerate is expecting 32 bit data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.I shouldn't make a new `SRC_STATE` object and delete it in each call of my function by calling `st=src_new(2,1,&er2);` and `src_delete(st);`but call them once is enough for the whole audio re-sampling.Also there is no need to using pointer for the `SRC_DATA` . I modified my code as below and it works fine now.

```
void BackEndAudio::ChangeSampleRate(BYTE* buf)
{
BYTE *onechbuf = new BYTE[3840];
int outputIndex = 0;

//convert Stereo to Mono
for (int n = 0; n < 7680; n+=8)
{
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+1];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+2];
    onechbuf[outputIndex++] = buf[n+3];
}

float *out=new float[160];

//change samplerate
sd.data_in=(float *)onechbuf;
sd.data_out=out;
sd.input_frames=960;
sd.output_frames=160;
sd.src_ratio=(double)1/6;
sd.end_of_input=0;
int er=src_process(st,&sd);
}
```